How is this function piece-wise linear?
I encountered this lemma in a research paper related to End-to-End inventory management model.
Please note that $d_{[t_1,t_2]} = \sum_{t=t_1}^{t_2} d_i$, where $d_t$ denotes demand at time instance t. $I_{t_1}$ denotes the inventory level at time $t_1$.
I could understand why $f(a)$ is a convex function. But I didn't understand why is it a piece-wise function. Subsequenly, I am not able to visualize how the function has extreme points at $d_{[t_1,s]}-I_{t_1}$?
Can you please help me understand how $f(a)$ is a piece-wise function and how it has extreme points at $d_{[t_1,s]}-I_{t_1}$?


Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4926302/how-is-this-function-piece-wise-linear

For a linear function $g(a)$, the function $g(a)^+=\max(g(a),0)$ is piecewise linear (with two pieces).  Also, finite  combinations (weighted sums) of piecewise linear functions are piecewise linear.  So $f(a)$ is piecewise linear.  Because $h\ge 0$ and $b\ge 0$, $f(a)$ is also convex.  For a convex piecewise linear function, the claim that “the optimal solution should be one of the extreme points” is a bit too strong because one of the slopes could be $0$, yielding an infinite number of optimal solutions. But it is true that at least one extreme point is optimal.
To find the extreme points, note that for $\max(g(a),0)$, the extreme point occurs where $g(a)=0$.

Can you please help out with how the extreme points came out to be $d_{[t_1,s]}−I_{t_1}$? I cant figure it out even though I have been trying to understand it for hours now.
